# How to copy input from from the clipboard using pbcopy and setting that to another file that can then be called by pbpaste

Tags: macos, copy-paste, pbcopy

I want to get the data from the main clipboard onto my own file so that when the user executes a command they can retrieve the information set upon that second file. Alternatively I could also `pbcopy` direcly into the second file and run that command with `pbpaste`. Could someone smarter than me tell me how to do this. I have searched for hours now.

Answer (score 0):

`pbpaste` reads from the clipboard/pasteboard and writes to stdout (as if you are pasting), so you can copy your pasteboard to a file using `pbpaste > filename`. You can then do whatever you want with the file. `pbcopy` puts something *onto* the pasteboard, so if you want to put a file's contents into the pasteboard you can do that with `pbcopy < filename`.

The `<` and `>` operators are shell redirection operators, which you can learn more about in a command-line or unix tutorial.